# Weird behavior with storing 2d array?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, malloc

I've included the code below but to summarize, the createMonster() function initializes the struct monster fields and then returns the struct pointer. The **readMonster() function should read information from an input.txt file and returns an array of createMonster() pointers. Ex: monsterList[i] = createMonster(x ,y ,z). To reiterate, createMonster() holds data of a single monster, and **readMonsters returns a list monsters with their createMonster data

The issue is that when I use the first for loop to loop through and fill monsterList[I] with the createMonster() data, and then print it to the screen, it works perfectly. However, Creating a second for loop that just prints monsterList[I] prints weird things to the screen. The only thing that prints correctly is the int population field. Here is the code below.

```
// omitting failed malloc checks for simplicity. Assume no mallocs failed.
#define BUFFERSIZE 50

typedef struct monster
{
   char *name;
   char *element;
   int population;
} monster; // An index

monster *createMonster(char *name, char *element, int population)
{
  // Sizeof(struct monster) for clarification.
  monster *monster = malloc(sizeof(struct monster));

  // Allocating memory for struct monster fields
  monster->name = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(name) + 1); // +1 null sentinel

  monster->element = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(element) + 1);

  // Initalizing fields based on function input parameters
  monster->name = name;
  monster->element = element;
  monster->population = population;

  // Return struct pointer
  return monster;
}

monster **readMonsters(FILE *ifp, int *monsterCount)
{
  // Initializing array of struct monster pointers
  monster **monsterList = NULL;
  // Buffer to store monster name and monster element
  char name_buffer[BUFFERSIZE], element_buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
  // Buffer to store amount of monsters in file
  int num_monsters = 0;
  // Buffer to store monstor population
  int population;
  // Iterative variable
  int i;

  // making monsterCount the address of num_monsters
  monsterCount = &num_monsters;

  // alloating monsterList and
  // simultanenously scaning the value of monsters from the file into the address of num_monsters,
  // which is monsterCount
  monsterList = malloc(sizeof(int *) * (fscanf(ifp, "%d", monsterCount)) + 1);

  // File parsing. Skipping a string based on known input.txt file structure
  fscanf(ifp, "%*s");

  // storing file information into the monsters' individual monster pointer.
  // using num_monsters for clarification and to avoid segmentation faulting

  /*  These two for loops are the issue. The first for loop prints everything to
   the screen correctly. Therefore, in this for loop, monsterList[I] holds all the
   correct createMonster() data. 
  The second for loop should just print the same information to the screen, 
  but it doesn't. What is going on with malloc?
   */

    for (i = 0; i < num_monsters; i++)
    {
      fscanf(ifp,"%s %s %d", name_buffer, element_buffer, &population);
      monsterList[i] = createMonster(name_buffer, element_buffer, population);
      // prints correctly
      printf("\n monsterList[%d]->name: %s, ->element: %s, ->population: %d\n", i, monsterList[i]->name, monsterList[i]->element, monsterList[i]->population);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < num_monsters; i++)
    {
      // does not print correctly
      printf("\n monsterList[%d]->name: %s, ->element: %s, ->population: %d\n", i, monsterList[i]->name, monsterList[i]->element, monsterList[i]->population);
    }

    return monsterList;
  }
```

Here is what prints to the screen:

// These are correct

monsterList[0]->name: StAugustine, ->element: Grass, ->population: 12

monsterList[1]->name: Zoysia, ->element: Grass, ->population: 8

monsterList[2]->name: WholeWheat, ->element: Bread, ->population: 6

monsterList[3]->name: MultiGrain, ->element: Bread, ->population: 10

monsterList[4]->name: Rye, ->element: Bread, ->population: 10

monsterList[5]->name: Cinnamon, ->element: Spice, ->population: 5

monsterList[6]->name: Pepper, ->element: Spice, ->population: 10

monsterList[7]->name: Pumpkin, ->element: Spice, ->population: 30

// (second for loop) These are not correct, except for the population from cell 1-7

monsterList[0]->name: pʛ??, ->element: pʛ??, ->population: -641705424

monsterList[1]->name: Pumpkin, ->element: Spice, ->population: 8

monsterList[2]->name: Pumpkin, ->element: Spice, ->population: 6

monsterList[3]->name: Pumpkin, ->element: Spice, ->population: 10

monsterList[4]->name: Pumpkin, ->element: Spice, ->population: 10

monsterList[5]->name: Pumpkin, ->element: Spice, ->population: 5

monsterList[6]->name: Pumpkin, ->element: Spice, ->population: 10

monsterList[7]->name: Pumpkin, ->element: Spice, ->population: 30

Apologies for any formatting errors.

Comment: You are overwriting the memory allocations with `monster->name = malloc(...)` and then `monster->name = name;` ditto with `monster->element`. Please use `strcpy()` to copy a string. But `monster->population = population;` is ok.

Comment: `monsterList = malloc(sizeof(int *) * (fscanf(ifp, "%d", monsterCount)) + 1);` `fscanf` returns the number of items scanned, not the value of any of them. In this case if the conversion was successful the return value is 1 and not enough memory is allocated. No good reason that isn't two steps. Read the value, perhaps do some validation on it, and then use the value to allocate. More readable, easier to watch in a debugger, and less likely to go wrong.

Comment: Just tried using strcpy(monster->name, name) and it works, except for array[0] and the array[1]. They are still being corrupted. @WeatherVane

Comment: @RetiredNinja Are you referring to the initial monsterList allocation in the readMonster function?

Comment: Here: `monsterList = malloc(sizeof(int *) * (fscanf(ifp, "%d", monsterCount)) + 1);` The  return value from `fscanf()` has nothing to do with the amount of memory needed. Nor has the `sizeof(int*)`. Should it be `malloc(sizeof(monster*) * num_monsters)`?

Comment: @WeatherVane I was curious about that too, thanks for clarifying that.

Answer (score 0):

The line: monsterList = malloc(sizeof(int *) * (fscanf(ifp, "%d", monsterCount)) + 1); was the issue.
Fix:

Using fscanf first to read the amount of monsters, and then using that value to allocate memory for monsterList